# Retuning values inside if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return

I've got this code;

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) {
    if (type.equals("Addition")) {
        return (num1 + num2);
    } else if (type.equals("Subtraction")) {
        return (num1 - num2);
    } else if (type.equals("Multiplication")) {
        return (num1 * num2);
    } else if (type.equals("Division")) {
        return (num1 / num2);
    }
}
```

I know the return statement should be outside the if statements and since it isn't the block doesn't work. I'm trying use a method that would give a different output depending on the users preference when the method is called.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I know the return statement should be outside the if statements " this is not a hard rule

Comment: If you only have four choices, change the last `else if (type.equals("Division"))` to `else`. It will work then.

Comment: Wow, okay. Thanks, works now. @AKSingh

Comment: @J.S.T you could also add `else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uknown type: " + type); }` which will fix your missing return and will have your method throw an Error/Exception when the passed type isn't one of the 4 Strings you expect.

Comment: If you simply changed the last `else if` to `else` any type that isn't "Addition", "Subtraction" or "Multiplication" will be seen as a divison. So `equate("PopeyeTheSailor", 2.0, 1.0);` would be treated the same as `equate("Division", 2.0, 1.0);`. It's of course up to you if that is a your desired behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but some alternatives:

the normal `switch` (switch statement)

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) {
    switch (type) {
        case "Addition": return (num1 + num2);
        case "Subtraction": return (num1 - num2);
        case "Multiplication": return (num1 * num2);
        case "Division": return (num1 / num2);
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unrecognized type: " + type);
    }
}
```

the switch expression (introduced in Java 12 (preview feature))

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) {
    return switch (type) {
        case "Addition" -> (num1 + num2);
        case "Subtraction" -> (num1 - num2);
        case "Multiplication" -> (num1 * num2);
        case "Division" -> (num1 / num2);
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unrecognized type: " + type);
    };
}
```

---

also worth mentioning, instead of using a `String` for type, an `enum` would be more indicated (IMO)

```
enum OperationType {
  ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION;
}
```

```
public double equate(OperationType type, double num1, double num2) {
    // any of given alternatives/answers, just change string into enum constant
    // e.g. case ADDITION: ...
    // or if (type == OperationType.ADDITION) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statetement regarding that the return inside the if is not allowed is incorrect. It's allowed to have the return values there, but in case all your if/elseif's are false, you also need to return something.

You could solve this by returning an exception when nothing matches in your if block. This makes that in all cases, you have a valid end state in the method.

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) {
    if (type.equals("Addition")) {
        return (num1 + num2);
    } else if (type.equals("Subtraction")) {
        return (num1 - num2);
    } else if (type.equals("Multiplication")) {
        return (num1 * num2);
    } else if (type.equals("Division")) {
        return (num1 / num2);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect type provided " + type);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, but not recommended in this case, you could return some kind of default value if the if block has nothing that passes

Comment: suggestion: include the `type` in the error message, much easier to debug/correct/understand

Answer (score 0):

u could set the answer to another variable then return that variable

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) {
    double result = 0;
    if (type.equals("Addition")) {
        result = num1 + num2;
    } else if (type.equals("Subtraction")) {
        result = num1 - num2;
    } else if (type.equals("Multiplication")) {
        result = num1 * num2;
    } else if (type.equals("Division")) {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you state that your function returns a `double`, then it must return a `double`, or throw an error.

If type does not equal `Addition`, `Subtraction` `Multiplication` or `Division` then the execution will run past the last `else if {}` block and will have nothing to return. (as if it were returning void.) As it void != double the function does not compile.

to solve this you need to deal with the erroneous case

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) throws Exception {
if (type.equals("Addition")) {
    return (num1 + num2);
} else if (type.equals("Subtraction")) {
    return (num1 - num2);
} else if (type.equals("Multiplication")) {
    return (num1 * num2);
} else if (type.equals("Division")) {
    return (num1 / num2);
}
// If the function has not returned yet then type was not any of the valid choices
throw new Exception("Invalid Type!");
```

}

or if you are certain type will always be valid, change the last block

```
public double equate(String type, double num1, double num2) throws Exception {
if (type.equals("Addition")) {
    return (num1 + num2);
} else if (type.equals("Subtraction")) {
    return (num1 - num2);
} else if (type.equals("Multiplication")) {
    return (num1 * num2);
    // by process of elimination, type must equal "Division" 
} else {          
        return (num1 / num2);
    }
}
```